# Why does the value in multiple CheckBoxList selected even though I specified one with the ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I am generating three separate CheckBoxList

C#:

```
//...
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    ListItem li = new ListItem((string)dr["LD"], dr["ID"]+"");
    cl1.Items.Add(li);
    cl2.Items.Add(li);
    cl2.Items.Add(li);
}
//...
SelectCheckBoxList("76", cl2);


private void SelectCheckBoxList(string valueToSelect, CheckBoxList lst)
{
    ListItem listItem = lst.Items.FindByValue(valueToSelect);
    //ListItem listItem = lst.Items.FindByText(valueToSelect);
    if (listItem != null) listItem.Selected = true;
}
```

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cl1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="UnorderedList">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cl2" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="UnorderedList">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cl3" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="UnorderedList">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Since they all have the same value but I only want the value in the `CheckBoxList` with the ID `cl2` selected. However, all three `CheckBoxList` has the item selected.

How can I resolve this please.

Comment: You are adding the same instance of `ListItem` to three different lists.  If you set it checked in one it will set all because it's the same instance.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh... wow... you are right :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference to the same `ListItem` is added to each list. Add a copy of the `ListItem` to each list instead:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    cl1.Items.Add(new ListItem((string)dr["LD"], dr["ID"]+""));
    cl2.Items.Add(new ListItem((string)dr["LD"], dr["ID"]+""));
    cl2.Items.Add(new ListItem((string)dr["LD"], dr["ID"]+""));
}
```